# Python calculations: floats and ints

Tags: python, floating-point, int

In a long code of 600 lines I have one part of the code that calculates something weird.

```
idl = 0
print type(dl), dl
idl = int(dl*10)+1
print idl
```

This returns:

```
<type 'float'> 0.1
1
```

This calculation is done in a definition in my code.
This is obviously not the expected result. The weird thing is, when I copy the code above in a separate python file:

```
idl = 0
dl = 0.1
print type(dl), dl
idl = int(dl*10)+1
print idl
```

I get:

```
<type 'float'> 0.1
2
```

What could be the origin of this problem? I've extracted these parts, to make the problem simple, but if you want I can give more information.

Comment: Casting to int doesn't round your number, but rather truncates it. Because of it you can get 0.999999 instead of 1 and so it gives 0 when cast to int. I'm not sure why the outcome can be different in different places though...

Comment: Perhaps the value of `dl` is not as close to .1 as it might seem in the first case, but Python is only printing it to limited precision. I suggest you print it with more precision (I am unfamiliar with the Python syntax for doing so) or print `dl-.1` to see the difference. As sashkello notes, if `dl` is slightly less than `.1`, then `dl*10` is slightly less than 1, and the conversion to `int` will truncate it to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eric Postpischil's comment is on-point.

Python tries to hide some of the ugliness of floating-point numbers from the casual user. Most of the time, it's fine. Sometimes, you get surprised. Many decimal numbers do not represent precisely in binary form -- they become repeating or extremely long fractions. Python's display code converts the binary floating point number into a decimal, sometimes rounding off to get to the right place.

Here's a solid reference on the topic: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

The code snippet you provide is correct, but you may wish to use `int(round(dl*10))`.

If the imprecise representation of decimal math in floating point causes you consternation -- like it might if you are working with money, for instance -- check out the decimal module: http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#module-decimal

The decimal module provides excellent facilities for doing decimal math, but it is somewhat more cumbersome to use than floating-point.

For what it's worth, this problem is not unique to Python. You will find similar problems in most programming languages (and a similar decimal-math library to solve the problems.)

Comment: Thank you, this answer really helps me out and it was in fact exactly the problem.